# Django Rest Framework: Get related specific model field in serializer from another model

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to return a Response including data from 2 linked models, where I can get a specific field value from another model. The models are:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('author_created',)

class Book(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author_name = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('book_created',)
```

Serializers are:

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('id', 'author')

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = AuthorSerializer(source='author_name')
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'book_name','name')
```

My response shows like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "book_name": "Himu",
        "name": {
            "id": 1,
            "author": "Humayun Ahmed"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "book_name": "Shanta's family",
        "name": {
            "id": 2,
            "author": "Jafar Iqbal"
        }
    }
]
```

But i want to show it like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "book_name": "Himu",
        "name": {
            "author": "Humayun Ahmed"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "book_name": "Shanta's family",
        "name": {
            "author": "Jafar Iqbal"
        }
    }
]
```

How can i get this output?

Comment: can't you just remove `id` from your fields in your `AuthorSerializer`?

Comment: No. If i remove it, i get an error

Comment: And what is that error?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this `name = AuthorSerializer(source='author_name.author')`

Reference : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source